# Bootstrap dropdown menu stuck in expanded position, doesn't respond to button

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4, electron, dropdown

I'm trying to make a simple sign in program for use in a podium at my office. All that this program is responsible for is allowing clients to put in their name, username, description of their problem, and click submit. this information will then get put into a CSV.

This all works fine, however the Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu I have included is always stuck open. It defaults to expanded when the page loads, and remains open regardless of clicking the button or not.

My code is almost exactly the same as the example code shown on Bootstraps site:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="btn btn-secondary btn btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Reason for your visit
           </button>
           <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="display: block">
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Dropoff')">Scantron dropoff</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Pickup')">Scantron pickup</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Wifi issues')">Wifi issues</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('DUO Enrollment issues')">DUO Enrollment issues</a>
                 <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Password Issues')">Password issues</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And here are my imports:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
```

[image: Here is a screenshot showing what is happening]

EDIT: This issue seems to only exist within the Electron/Node.JS enviornment. running my html/css within chrome (by launching the index.html file) works as expected and does not show any errors in the developer console.

Comment: What error re you seeing in the developer console? Seems like ome js is broken.

Comment: Not seeing any errors in the dev console, at least not until I made the changes mentioned by @J. Sadi in his answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `bootstraps.bundle.js`, too. Otherwise it will not toggle:

```
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

*take note that you're importing jquery before importing boottsraps js-file*

---

You also have to remove `style="display: block"` from your dropdown-menu. This `display: block;` is the reason why your menu stucks in expanded position.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- imported jquery, bootstraps css and bootstraps bundle.js -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Reason for your visit
      </button>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <!-- removed style="display: block;" -->
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Dropoff')">Scantron dropoff</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Pickup')">Scantron pickup</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Wifi issues')">Wifi issues</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('DUO Enrollment issues')">DUO Enrollment issues</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Password Issues')">Password issues</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not change the behavior at all. I imported it like above and I checked to make sure that file existed in my node_modules as well, and I can confirm that it is there.

Comment: edited my answer, you have to Import the bootstrap.bundle.js oder bootstrap.bundle.min.js

Comment: Having used this import, I'm now getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at setTransitionEndSupport (util.js:56)
    at util.js:147
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:9
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:10`

I'm wondering if maybe the issue is with my jquery install? not sure how to diagnose.

Comment: this error could occure, because you're importing `bootstrap.bundle.js` before you've imported `jquery.js`. You have to import jquery first.

Comment: Jquery is imported before everything else, unfortunately.

Comment: in this case maybe your jquery-version is to old? As you can see in my example its working well.

Comment: I imported a fresh install of jquery and I get the same problem sadly. This is pretty strange.

Comment: as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9w8yg0ro/) i'm getting the exactly the same error, if i've imported jquery **after** bootstraps js… i think its an problem with your dependency order.

Comment: I'm literally using the exact import statements above and still receive that error. I also tried using my own local node_module imports in that same order to no avail

Comment: you could also import popper.js and the "normal" bootstrap.js instead of bootstrap.bundle.js .. but, in this case you have to import jqurey first, too.

Comment: Update, this code works fine when running the HTML page straight inside chrome, but does not work inside my electron application. I have updated my original post with this information as well

Answer (score 0):

> "the Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu I have included is always stuck open"

The dropdown remains "open" because it has inline style `"style:display:block"`. **Remove this and follow the normal dropdown structure**...

```
     <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Reason for your visit
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Dropoff')">Scantron dropoff</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Scantron Pickup')">Scantron pickup</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Wifi issues')">Wifi issues</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('DUO Enrollment issues')">DUO Enrollment issues</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:dropDownSelection('Password Issues')">Password issues</a>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ViKYGOigbL

Comment: Having removed that, I don't get any function from the button at all. adding the `style = display:block` was a solution suggested to me for my original issue where the menu did not open at all.